# C++ вызов деструктора при изменяющимся типе

Tags: c++

Столкнулся с проблемой вызова деструктора в структуре, где тип данных может меняться. Чтобы удалить переменную `b` в структуре надо явно прописать это в деструкторе. Если `T` будет указателем, то надо писать `delete b`, если переменной, то `delete &b`.

```
class B {
    public:
    virtual ~B() { cout<<"B"; }
};

class D : virtual public B {
    public:
    ~D() { cout<<"D"; }
};

template <typename T>
struct S {
    S() {}
    T b;
    ~S() { cout<<"S"; }
};

int main() {
    S<B*> s = S<B*>();
    s.b = new D;

    s.~S();    //выводит только "S"
    
    return 0;
}
```

Если запустить код то выведется только **"S"**. Как написать чтобы работало во всех случаях?

Comment: "*если переменной, то delete &b*" — интересно посмотреть кусочек кода, как именно вы себе представляете удаление переменной? :) "*выведется только "S"*" — опять же, вы в этом уверены? В вашем коде деструктор вызовется дважды, выведется "SS". А вообще — ну, если вы реально хотите использовать такой дизайн, можно, например, либо воспользоваться специализацией, либо добавить как параметр удалитель... Кстати, сам вопрос задан неверно: деструктор *для типа **`T`*** будет вызван...

Comment: Деструктор для **T** не вызывается, в этом и проблема, надо прописать `delete b` чтоб он вызвался, а если **T** не указатель, то ошибка

Comment: `S<unique_ptr<B>>  s; s.b.reset(new D);`

Comment: Деструктор для ***T*** вызывается. Деструктор **для указателя** — т.е. простой переменной, содержащей адрес — ничего не делает. Иначе бы вы оказались в глубокой, гм... при наличии двух переменных-указателей, указывающих на один адрес. Не путайте деструктор объекта с деструктором указателя на объект!! А у вас тип T — это тип указателя. Вы же не ждете, что в коде `int main(){ B* b = new B; }` будет вызван деструктор `B`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас прямые вызовы конструктора и деструктора.

```cpp
S<B*> s = S<B*>();
s.~S();
```

Это делать не надо, так как всё делается автоматически. В полях структур тоже будет вызван деструктор.
*"если переменной, то delete &b" - не надо.*

```cpp
S<B*> s;
```

Делать шаблонный объект из указателя не желательно, так как удаление объекта, заданного указателем не будет вызвано автоматически. А в шаблонах не реализовано иметь разные функции, в зависимости от того, тип указатель или нет.
Хорошим выходом будет использовать только умные указатели, в деструкторе которых удаление указателя будет вызвано автоматически.

```cpp
S < std :: unique_ptr < B > > s2 ;
s2 . b . reset ( new D ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `s.~S()` писать не надо, это происходит автоматически.
2. > Если `T` будет указателем, то надо писать `delete b`, если переменной, то `delete &b`.

   `delete &b` делать не надо, потому что `b` не был бы создан через `new`.

   Для `delete b` можно было бы сделать вот так:

   ```
   if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<T>)
       delete b;
   ```

   Но самом деле лучше ничего в деструктор `S` не добавлять, а как вам правильно советуют, вместо сырого указателя использовать умный: `S<std::unique_ptr<B>> s; s.b = std::make_unique<D>();`.

   Вообще, звать руками `new`, `delete` и деструкторы - дурной тон, если только вы не пишете свой контейнер или умный указатель.